# Javascript is not redirecting to the index

Tags: javascript, html, api, redirect

I am using the following JS code to post directly to an API, however after posting im trying to send it to my "index.html" it does not do that. It actually send me to the API website confirming that it was able to post the request.

```
<div class="formbold-main-wrapper">
  <!-- Author: FormBold Team -->
  <!-- Learn More: https://formbold.com -->
  <div class="formbold-form-wrapper">
    <form action="https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/d73hngqld5k2l" method="post" id="sheetdb-form">
        <div class="formbold-steps">
            <ul>
                <li class="formbold-step-menu1 active">
                    <span>1</span>
                    Sign Up
                </li>
                <li class="formbold-step-menu2">
                    <span>2</span>
                    Message
                </li>
                <li class="formbold-step-menu3">
                    <span>3</span>
                    Confirm
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="formbold-form-step-1 active">
          <div class="formbold-input-flex">
            <div>
                <label for="firstname" class="formbold-form-label"> First name </label>
                <input
                type="text"
                name="data[number]"
                placeholder="Andrio"
                id="firstname"
                class="formbold-form-input"
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="lastname" class="formbold-form-label"> Last name </label>
                <input
                type="text"
                name="lastname"
                placeholder="Dolee"
                id="lastname"
                class="formbold-form-input"
                />
            </div>
          </div>
  
          <div class="formbold-input-flex">
              <div>
                  <label for="dob" class="formbold-form-label"> Date of Birth </label>
                  <input 
                  type="date" 
                  name="dob" 
                  id="dob" 
                  class="formbold-form-input"
                  />
              </div>
              <div>
                  <label for="email" class="formbold-form-label"> Email Address </label>
                  <input
                  type="email"
                  name="email"
                  placeholder="example@mail.com"
                  id="email"
                  class="formbold-form-input"
                  />
              </div>
          </div>
  
          <div>
              <label for="address" class="formbold-form-label"> Address </label>
              <input
              type="text"
              name="address"
              id="address"
              placeholder="Flat 4, 24 Castle Street, Perth, PH1 3JY"
              class="formbold-form-input"
              />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="formbold-form-step-2">
          <div>
            <label for="message" class="formbold-form-label"> Message </label>
            <textarea
              rows="6"
              name="message"
              id="message"
              placeholder="Type your message"
              class="formbold-form-input"
            ></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="formbold-form-step-3">
          <div class="formbold-form-confirm">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.
            </p>

            <div>
              <button class="formbold-confirm-btn active">
                <svg width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 22 22" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <circle cx="11" cy="11" r="10.5" fill="white" stroke="#DDE3EC"/>
                <g clip-path="url(#clip0_1667_1314)">
                <path d="M9.83343 12.8509L15.1954 7.48828L16.0208 8.31311L9.83343 14.5005L6.12109 10.7882L6.94593 9.96336L9.83343 12.8509Z" fill="#536387"/>
                </g>
                <defs>
                <clipPath id="clip0_1667_1314">
                <rect width="14" height="14" fill="white" transform="translate(4 4)"/>
                </clipPath>
                </defs>
                </svg>
                Yes! I want it.
              </button>

              <button class="formbold-confirm-btn">
                <svg width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 22 22" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <circle cx="11" cy="11" r="10.5" fill="white" stroke="#DDE3EC"/>
                <g clip-path="url(#clip0_1667_1314)">
                <path d="M9.83343 12.8509L15.1954 7.48828L16.0208 8.31311L9.83343 14.5005L6.12109 10.7882L6.94593 9.96336L9.83343 12.8509Z" fill="#536387"/>
                </g>
                <defs>
                <clipPath id="clip0_1667_1314">
                <rect width="14" height="14" fill="white" transform="translate(4 4)"/>
                </clipPath>
                </defs>
                </svg>
                No! I don’t want it.
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="formbold-form-btn-wrapper">
          <button class="formbold-back-btn">
            Back
          </button>

          <button class="formbold-btn">
              Next Step
              <svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <g clip-path="url(#clip0_1675_1807)">
              <path d="M10.7814 7.33312L7.20541 3.75712L8.14808 2.81445L13.3334 7.99979L8.14808 13.1851L7.20541 12.2425L10.7814 8.66645H2.66675V7.33312H10.7814Z" fill="white"/>
              </g>
              <defs>
              <clipPath id="clip0_1675_1807">
              <rect width="16" height="16" fill="white"/>
              </clipPath>
              </defs>
              </svg>
          </button>
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap');
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  body {
    font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  }
  .formbold-main-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 48px;
  }

  .formbold-form-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 550px;
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
  }

  .formbold-steps {
    padding-bottom: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDE3EC;
  }
  .formbold-steps ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    gap: 40px;
  }
  .formbold-steps li {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #536387;
  }
  .formbold-steps li span {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #DDE3EC;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #536387;
  }
  .formbold-steps li.active {
    color: #07074D;;
  }
  .formbold-steps li.active span {
    background: #6A64F1;
    color: #FFFFFF;
  }

  .formbold-input-flex {
    display: flex;
    gap: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 22px;
  }
  .formbold-input-flex > div {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .formbold-form-input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 13px 22px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #DDE3EC;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #536387;
    outline: none;
    resize: none;
  }
  .formbold-form-input:focus {
    border-color: #6a64f1;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  }
  .formbold-form-label {
    color: #07074D;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 24px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .formbold-form-confirm {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDE3EC;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
  }
  .formbold-form-confirm p {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #536387;
    margin-bottom: 22px;
    width: 75%;
  }
  .formbold-form-confirm > div {
    display: flex;
    gap: 15px;
  }

  .formbold-confirm-btn {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 10px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 0.5px solid #DDE3EC;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #536387;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  }
  .formbold-confirm-btn {
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  }
  .formbold-confirm-btn.active {
    background: #6A64F1;
    color: #FFFFFF;
  }

  .formbold-form-step-1,
  .formbold-form-step-2,
  .formbold-form-step-3 {
    display: none;
  }
  .formbold-form-step-1.active,
  .formbold-form-step-2.active,
  .formbold-form-step-3.active {
    display: block;
  }

  .formbold-form-btn-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    gap: 25px;
    margin-top: 25px;
  }
  .formbold-back-btn {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: none;
    color: #07074D;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    display: none;
  }
  .formbold-back-btn.active {
    display: block;
  }
  .formbold-btn {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    border: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    background-color: #6A64F1;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .formbold-btn:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  }

</style>

  <script>
    const scriptURL = 'https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/d73hngqld5k2l'
            const form = document.forms['sheetdb-form']

    var form = document.getElementById('sheetdb-form');
form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  fetch(form.action, {
      method : "POST",
      body: new FormData(document.getElementById("sheetdb-form")),
  }).then(
      response => response.json()
  ).then((html) => {
    // you can put any JS code here
    newWindow = window.open("", "_blank");

request = $.ajax({ ... my request which returns a url to load ... })

request.done((function(_this) {
        return function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          return window.location = "index.html";
        };
      })(this));

  });
});
</script>

<script>
  const stepMenuOne = document.querySelector('.formbold-step-menu1')
  const stepMenuTwo = document.querySelector('.formbold-step-menu2')
  const stepMenuThree = document.querySelector('.formbold-step-menu3')

  const stepOne = document.querySelector('.formbold-form-step-1')
  const stepTwo = document.querySelector('.formbold-form-step-2')
  const stepThree = document.querySelector('.formbold-form-step-3')

  const formSubmitBtn = document.querySelector('.formbold-btn')
  const formBackBtn = document.querySelector('.formbold-back-btn')

  formSubmitBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    if(stepMenuOne.className == 'formbold-step-menu1 active') {
        event.preventDefault()

        stepMenuOne.classList.remove('active')
        stepMenuTwo.classList.add('active')

        stepOne.classList.remove('active')
        stepTwo.classList.add('active')

        formBackBtn.classList.add('active')
        formBackBtn.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
          event.preventDefault()

          stepMenuOne.classList.add('active')
          stepMenuTwo.classList.remove('active')

          stepOne.classList.add('active')
          stepTwo.classList.remove('active')

          formBackBtn.classList.remove('active')

        })

      } else if(stepMenuTwo.className == 'formbold-step-menu2 active') {
        event.preventDefault()

        stepMenuTwo.classList.remove('active')
        stepMenuThree.classList.add('active')

        stepTwo.classList.remove('active')
        stepThree.classList.add('active')

        formBackBtn.classList.remove('active')
        formSubmitBtn.textContent = 'Submit'
      } else if(stepMenuThree.className == 'formbold-step-menu3 active') {
        document.querySelector('form').submit()
      }
  })
    

  
</script>
```

I tried reading multiple posts and modifying my JS but it still does not work for me, I cant seem to find the error.

Comment: `return window.location = index.html;` ... do you really have a variable called `index` with a property `html` ... or should that be `return window.location = "index.html";` - check the browser console for errors (debugging 101)

Comment: If `index = { html: "http://example.com" }`, then `window.location = index.html` might make sense. Otherwise, you almost certainly wanted `window.location = "index.html"`.

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you for the quick response, I'm kind of new I tried double checking but I was not able to find the error, I updated my post with my full code incase you seem to find the error. I did try to run the browser console.

Comment: @Amadan Thank you as well, I appreciate your help. Im new and I'm trying my best to understand want I'm doing wrong but I can't seem to find it. Every time I post the form it redirects me to the API website.

Comment: you really do NOT need to include ANY CSS for this question, nor most of the HTML to be honest... The idea is to post MINIMAL code that demonstrates the issue